# how to replace double back slash with single back slash in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
buf= 'b"\\\x00\\\x00\\\x1a\\\x00/H\\\x00\\\x00\\\xf8f\\\x14'""'
```

I need:

```
buf= 'b"\x00\x00\x1a\x00/H\x00\x00\xf8f \x14'""'
```

I tried: `buf=buf.replace("\\","\")`
But I am getting error: `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

Comment: Your input throws a syntax error. And there are no backslashes in your output. `\x` denotes a hexadecimal representation of a byte; the string doesn't actually contain backslashes. If you try `print('b"\x00\x00\x1a\x00/H\x00\x00\xf8f \x14')` you won't see any backslashes.

Comment: Thanks. How do I save it in a string that is getting printed ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to escape each backslash with another backslash:

```
buf=buf.replace("\\\\","\\")
```

Or, you can use raw strings:

```
buf=buf.replace(r"\\",r"\")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape `\` with a `\`. So replacing `\` becomes `\\` and replacing `\\` becomes `\\\\`

```
buf= 'b"\\x00\\x00\\x1a\\x00/H\\x00\\x00\\xf8f\\x14'""

buf=buf.replace("\\\\","\\") # give b"\x00\x00\x1a\x00/H\x00\x00\xf8f\x14
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code

```
buf=buf.replace("\\","\")
```

the first backslash will consider as an escape-sequence and will read the next character with special meaning. so in this stage "\" it will skip the second " so it will raise

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

replace your code with

```
buf=buf.replace(r"\\",r"\")
```

here 'r' is used to read the string completely,it will skip/avoid the escape sequances